# Can I set up the GUI or daemon to use a non-standard blockchain location in Windows?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, windows, blockchain-data

In Windows, it's comfortable to double-click the link/icon to a program (as opposed to using the command line).  The problem is that the default links/icons for the GUI or daemon (`monerod`) don't let the GUI or daemon use a non-default location of the blockchain.

I save the blockchain on a different, bigger drive.  When I open the GUI or daemon with double-clicking the link/icon, it automatically starts to re-download the blockchain to the standard location.  Can this conundrum be solved?

Comment: Symlinks? http://superuser.com/a/1020825/122662

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, this can actually be done fairly simply.  These options are slightly technical, but not terribly difficult, and only have to be done once.  There are a couple quick ways.

Option 1 - Make a copy of the shortcut link used for launching the GUI (or `monerod`).  Then right-click the copied shortcut to edit the shortcut's properties; and then add at the end of the `Target:` line/box `--data-dir \path\where\bitmonero\folder\is`. Click `OK` to save.  Double-clicking the link will launch the program with the `--data-dir` flag, which will be pointing to where you're keeping your copy of the blockchain.

Option 2 is to create and open a new text (*.txt) document, which you can do just by opening up Notepad.  Enter `C:\path\to\monerod.exe --data-dir \path\to\bitmonero\folder`.  Save the file with whatever name you like.  And then change the file extension from `txt` to `bat`.  This file will now behave just like the shortcut link from Option 1.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using a symbolic link, in Windows it's done with the `mklink` command:

First make sure monero gui (and daemon) are stopped.

Move the lmdb folder from `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` to its new destination (here D:\Monero\Blockchain).
(might work with the whole bitmonero folder moved and a bitmonero link in ProgramData, not tested this way as i don't mind the few MBs occupied by the log and p2pstate.bin on my SSD)

Open a command-line with administrator rights then:

```
CD /D C:\ProgramData\bitmonero

MKLINK /D lmdb D:\Monero\Blockchain\lmdb
```

This way you don't have to change any configuration / scripts or add parameters into shortcuts, as all programs see it as if the blockchain was still in its default location.